# Open network drive from Salesforce field or a custom link

Tags: custom-button, custom-field

I tried creating a custom field and a custom link on standard object with the link:
file:///Users/sk/downloads/index.html
It doesn't open a new page at all. Even if I try open as a new tab/new window, it shows me a blank page with url about:blank. The same happens with a custom link.

Has any one faced the same issue & found a solution for it?

Comment: How did you create the link? It looks like a file on your own computer, that can't work.

Answer (score 1):

have a look here, a similar question has been raised on DEVForce
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Best-Practices-Discussion/HYPERLINK-formula-to-link-to-our-network-works-in-IE-but-not/td-p/112491